# Google places API restrict to 'cities' for ANY part of the world

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

How can I google places API to search and return cities only?

I have achieved this for the UK by explicitly stating 'UK' in the script. The result is for example, if searching 'london,' the results show London and not 'london, united kingdom'  - this is fine.

But I would like to achieve the above for any city in the world. If I search Paris, the API will return 'Paris, France' and not just 'Paris' as I prefer.

HTML:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&sensor=false&libraries=places&region=UK"></script>
```

CLIENT.JS

```
function initializeCitySearch() {
 var options = {
  types: ['(cities)']
 };

 var input = document.getElementById('city');
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Strip country names if the occur last and after a comma,  or am I missing something?

Comment: do you mean remove '&region=UK' within the script? If so, I did that but then it returns city and the country

Comment: If country names are stripped, how will the user be able to tell apart predictions for "Paris, France" and "Paris, TX, United States"?

Comment: I probably assumed the API would provide both options as the typed "paris"